# Why some USB Serial converters work and others don't on specific hardware?

Tags: serial-port, serial, rs232

I went online and brought a pack of the cheapest USB to Serial adaptor, put TX on RX and RX on TX and was able to communicate between the 2 ports without any issue.

So I plug the thing in a device that uses RS232, connected using my favourite software with the right bound rate and it started to send garbage to my screen. Then I replace the cable with a way more expensive cable, use the same configuration, and it worked.

I don't understand. The configuration is done by software, if it was a quality issue, it should affect my tests using 2 of the cheap cables in my computer.

Anyone understand why this happen?

If anyone is wondering the difference bettwen the cables, here are the lsusb of the output.

Expensive one:

> Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04d8:00df Microchip Technology, Inc. MCP2200 USB Serial Port Emulator

Cheap one:

> Bus 001 Device 011: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port / Mobile Action MA-8910P

Answer (score 1):

This is largely (almost always) due to the manufacturers of cheap USB => Serial converters not using true FTDI chips, generally cheap knockoffs.

USB *is* a serial bus, **U**niversal**S**erial**B**us

Serial comes in MANY forms (Although most people mean rs232 and rs485), so the makers of converters/cable are generally targeting an audience, such as networking equipment consoles, programming radios, etc. So the chis can do much more, but the device has to be limited to avoid the user potentially making mistakes like plugging a 5v into a 1.8v serial system. That can let out the magic smoke. ;)

So the function of the chip is restricted by the creator to make it fit a specific function, where another creator could use the same chip for another purpose. While all the while trying to make it "work" without making it "dangerous" to what it is plugged into.

In fact in HAM radio world when someone is having difficulty programming a radio, the first thing to ask is "How much did you pay for the cable"

The next issue will be drivers, some people love to reinvent the wheel, and each simple device has to have a special vendor driver (At least in windows word) making the second point of failure the person who wrote the driver. Was it for performance, or profit?

Funny thing, the linux kernel native supports every USB serial adapter I have ever tossed at it, including the ones others throw away because they cannot find the correct windows driver!

YOU CAN get more universal by looking at things like FTDI chip programmers and adjustable voltage UART/TTL like [https://www.amazon.com/DSD-TECH-SH-U09C5-Converter-Support/dp/B07WX2DSVB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WX2DSVB) you take the burden of knowing what you are doing, but you can talk to just about anything serial. Or you can get something like a bus pirate and explore things yu are no even sure what they are in relative safety. http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate

Answer (score 0):

Had similar experience.
The inexpensive USB-RS232 adapters performed erratically: some days no issues at all, but then at other times, most or all characters were garbled.

Turns out that the ground connection on the USB side of the adapter was not shorted to pin 5 of the DB-9 connector. So signal ground relied on each end on the serial link to have the exact same ground.

When both USB adapters are connected to the same PC host, the ground issue is severely lessened.  Each USB end is connected to the same PC, therefore the exact same ground.  The RS-232 sides of the adapters are both using the same floating ground.

For your target device, make sure its power supply is using the same power strip as the PC host.  Or connect a short, large (small gauge) copper wire between grounds of the target device and PC.

Of course a simple continuity test using a DMM could confirm if your adapters have a similar broken ground connection.

---

The "reliable" and "unreliable" USB-RS232 adapters that I have use the same Prolific PL2303 converter chip.  So do not blame this converter chip as the culprit or indicator of this missing ground connection.

Comment: I did tried a couple of the cheaper usb converter (to make sure it was not 2 or 3 bad ones), I even disassemble one to see it there was no issue. But your post intrigues me, because the wire used in the cable is "hair thin".  When I get the time, I will try to replace the wire with 23 AWG (CAT-6 wire) and test again. Thanks for sharing your experience.